# Linux geocoder program?

Tags: geocoding, linux

I run a portable Linux box with an open street map tile server to provide maps for amateur radio emergency communications using APRS.

If needed to, I want a way to convert an address to a latitude and longitude where I do not have Internet connectvity.

Are there any Linux (in particular Ubuntu) geocoder utility's which will convert an address into lat/long?

Comment: a local geocoder with a database (are you looking for a world wide data?) see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation#Ubuntu.2FDebian

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with US data then the Tiger Geocoder runs on Linux...  see [this link](http://dracodoc.github.io/2015/11/17/Geocoding/)